# R Summary function leaving empty records behind

Tags: r, summary

Just a quick one, I'm trying to eliminate a string of text in my dataset in a specific column. When I call summary(mydata$myanimals), I get a strange result in the form of:

Ant: 100
Bat: 100
Cat: 100
Dog: 0
Emu: 100

Why would there be a "0" for records labeled "Dog". I've tried dplyr to filter it out, but it remains like this when calling the summary function. Any insights? I'd like to get rid of Dog all together but it won't go away.

Comment: It don't help to answer your question when you write down quick...can you please give us a working example with data of what you are doing.

Comment: Agreeing and emphasizing: we'd like to help. We have no idea whether mydata is a data.frame, data.table, or list. We don't know what data type myanimals is: factor? numeric vector with named elements? A minimal working example would make it possible to help you.

Comment: Hard to give an example as my data is 3M rows. It is more just whether anyone had any conceptual ideas as to why a zero would appear under an animal "type". I'm working with a df and the column is a factor

Comment: Use `dput(head(mydata))` and paste the output.

Comment: The answer to the riddle will lead through it being a factor and then `droplevels`. But in the future, please use `str()` or `dput(head(my_data))` to provide us with _something_ to go on. Otherwise, trying to help quickly becomes very frustrating guesswork. And frustrated people down vote and vote to close questions.

Comment: structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("Ant", "Bat", 
"Cat", "Dog", "Emu", "Elephant", 
"Tiger"), class = "factor")

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys,

myData$myanimals<-droplevels(myData$myanimals) worked nicely